# Resizing right panel of RadPageView in backstage mode - Telerik WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

How can I resize right panel (panel which shows pages list) of RadPageView in backstage mode? I need to make it smaller in width.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set width & height size like this:

```
this.radPageView1.GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(0).MinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 0);
```

[image: screenshot]

Also set size with designer like this:

Click on `RadPageView Task` then change `Item Area Width`

[image: screenshot]

To set margin for `RadPageView`  use this :

```
this.radPageView1.GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(0).Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(-20, 0, 0, 0);
```

Also set margin with designer like this:

Click on `RadPageView Task` then `Edit UI Element` then click on `StripViewItemContainer` change `margin`

[image: screenshot]